# Android URL Connect connectErrno

Tags: android, sockets, networking, io

Basically have an Android service continuous making http requests to my server. It does this by spinning off a new Thread for each URLconnection requests. However, I keep getting this error and I have no idea what it means:
Runnable class:

```
    private class getData implements Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run(){
            while(true) {
                try {
                    //define url object and set headers
                    URL url = new URL("http://172.17.67.187:1300/test_service");
                    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    urlConnection.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
                    urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(3000/* milliseconds */);
                    urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                    urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);  //enable output (body data)
                    urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");// set header
                    urlConnection.connect();
                    //Read data response from server
                    InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                    bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                    String line;
                    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                        result.append(line).append("\n");
                    }
                        Log.e("result", result.toString());
    //                  Log.e("sending broadcast","heki");
    //                  Intent response = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    //                  response.putExtra("message",result.toString());
    //                  sendBroadcast(response);
                        result.setLength(0);
                        Log.e("result", result.toString());

                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    String err_msg = "";
                    StackTraceElement[] errors =  ex.getStackTrace();
                    for(StackTraceElement err : errors){
                        err_msg += err.toString() + "\n";
                    }
                    Log.e("network exception", err_msg);
                }
                finally {
                    if (bufferedReader != null) {
                        try {
                            bufferedReader.close();
                        } catch (IOException ex) {
                            Log.e("buffer read close error", "");
                        }
                    }
                }
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(3000);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    Log.e("interrupt exception", "");
                }
            }
        }
    }
        public int onStartCommand(Intent service, int flags, int start_id){
        status = 1;
        Log.e("hello","im started");
        Thread pingServer = new Thread(new getData());
        pingServer.start();
        return START_STICKY;

    }

Error Message:`E/network exception: libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:169)
                     libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:122)
                     java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:183)
                     java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:452)
                     java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:884)
                     com.android.okhttp.internal.Platform.connectSocket(Platform.java:117)
                     com.android.okhttp.internal.http.SocketConnector.connectRawSocket(SocketConnector.java:160)
                     com.android.okhttp.internal.http.SocketConnector.connectCleartext(SocketConnector.java:67)
                     com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:152)
                     com.android.okhttp.Connection.connectAndSetOwner(Connection.java:185)
                     com.android.okhttp.OkHttpClient$1.connectAndSetOwner(OkHttpClient.java:128)
                     com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.nextConnection(HttpEngine.java:342)
                     com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:331)
                     com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:249)
                     com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:437)
                     com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:114)
                     com.example.talhaali.alarmclockapp.pingServer$getData.run(pingServer.java:38)
                     java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)`
```

Comment: which line of the code triggers the `IOException`?

Comment: `I keep getting this error ` ??? Which error?